# Xcode breakpoint [NSExceptionRaise] vs -[NSExceptionRaise]

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode, breakpoints

Xcode:Run>Show>Breakpoints

I've added the obligatory **`[NSExceptionRaise]`** and **`objc_exception_throw`** yet when I close the Breakpoints window and then return Xcode adds a third breakpoint:  **`-[NSExceptionRaise]`**. Does this mean **`[NSExceptionRaise]`** is wrong and **I should delete it?** Or are they both helpful? If so in what way are they functionally different?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct breakpoint is:

```
-[NSException raise]
```

You're instructing the debugger to break on the -raise method of the NSException class. "[NSExceptionRaise]" is (meaning no disrespect) nonsense. :-)

You don't need both, as far as I know. objc_exception_throw is the "new" way, whereas -[NSException raise] is the "old" way. I *believe* if you're on Leopard or later, only objc_exception_throw will be called. 10.4 or prior will call -[NSException raise].

Comment: can anyone verify that 10.5+ *only* calls **objc_exception_throw**? if so i can forget about this [NSException raise] nonsense entirely.

Comment: As of 10.5, -[NSException raise] calls objc_exception_throw.  This is why you don't need both.

Answer (score 0):

The newly added breakpoint is to `-[NSException raise]`, which is distinct from `[NSExceptionRaise]` in that the latter is an object method (`NSException` being the class, `raise` being the message). I don't know what the latter is, and I suspect XCode is trying to be intelligent about what you entered v. what it thinks you meant.

Answer (score 0):

You have to preface the method with either a plus or minus character because the debugger uses the headers to locate and define the symbol. Different methods can have the same name but methods prefaced by a "+" are class methods and those prefaced by "-" are instance methods. Without the plus or minus the debugger has no idea what method you wanted.