# CABasicAnimation causes freeze

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have this code :

```
- (void) animationErreur {
CABasicAnimation* fade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
fade.fromValue = (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.0f];
fade.fromValue = (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
fade.toValue = (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.0f];
[fade setDuration:1];
[self.topBar.layer addAnimation:fade forKey:@"fadeAnimation"];
}
```

Every time i call it, it works but if i click on the view during the animation, it crash. I have added the quartcore framework into my class. This code is called when i click on a button.

Any idea?

Comment: what is the crash error

Comment: i have only (lldb) on the debugger

Comment: also Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = 0x0)

Comment: add an exception breakpoint in Xcode and thus you should be able to give more information on the error. On how to do that see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798709/xcode-breakpoint-nsexceptionraise-vs-nsexceptionraise

Comment: [fade setDuration:1]; you are setting duration as 1 u need to set FLT_MAX Then it wont freeze

Comment: did u add exception break point so that u can get clear idea about your crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fade.toValue = (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.0f].CGColor;
```

You've to add the `.CGColor` at the end for the toValue line.

```
- (void) animationErreur {
    CABasicAnimation* fade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
    fade.fromValue = (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    fade.toValue = (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.0f].CGColor;
    [fade setDuration:1];
    [self.topBar.layer addAnimation:fade forKey:@"fadeAnimation"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works! I have tried to add an exception breakpoint but by adding CGColor the problem is solved. Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Try to make your animation object global. EXE_Bad_ACCESS is generally due to unreachability of a object in arc.